# Is there a way to start over (to reset) items numeration on tkinter Canvas?

Tags: tkinter

In tkinter  Canvas after deleting an item , every time you create a new item, it's ID value is bigger than the previous one. Even if you delete all items (.delete'all') , the new item's value is never number #1 again, numeration will be continued  after last created/deleted item.
Is there a way to reset numeration without deleting and creating new Canvas?

```
import tkinter
t = tkinter.Canvas()
t.pack()
for j in range (5):
    for i in range(1, 11):
        item=t.create_line((0, i, i, 100), tag= 'line')
    print(t.find_all())
    t.delete("all")

mainloop()
```

In the code above after creating 5 new items I delete them and expect the numeration order to be reset.

As a result I got

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
```

But i would like to get :

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to start over (to reset) items numeration on tkinter Canvas?

No, there is not.